# Finding ® in a string of text

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, text

Let me rephrase my question:

I am reading in text where one of the characters is the registered symbol, ®, from a text file that has no problem displaying the symbol. When I try to print the string after reading it from the file, the symbol is an unprintable character. When I read in the string and split the string to characters and convert the character to an Int16 and print out the hex, I get 0xFFFD. I specify `Encoding.UTF8` when I open the `StreamReader`.

Here is what I have

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/Hormel") + "/nutrition_data.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //after spliting the file on '~'
        items[i] = scrubData(utf8.GetString(utf8.GetBytes(items[i].ToCharArray())));
        //items[i] = scrubData(items[i]); //original
    }
}
```

Here is the scrubData function

```
private String scrubData(string data)
        {
            string newStr = String.Empty;
            try
            {

                if (data.Contains("HORMEL"))
                {
                    string[] s = data.Split(' ');
                    foreach(string str in s)
                    {
                        if (str.Contains("HORMEL"))
                        {
                            char[] ch = str.ToCharArray();                            
                            for(int i=0; i<ch.Length; i++)
                            {
                                EventLogProvider.LogInformation("LoadNutritionInfoTask", "Test", ch[i] + " = " + String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToInt16(ch[i])));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
return String.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogProvider.LogInformation("LoadNutritionInfoTask", "ScrubData", ex.Message);
                return data;
            }
        }
```

I'm not concerned with what is being returned right now, I am printing out the characters and the hex codes that correspond to them.

Comment: Ummm... just search for "®"?

Comment: How about you just try it and find out which is right, if either?

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 When I search for "®" it does not match to the symbol.

Comment: You haven't shown us _how_ you search for the symbol, so we cannot say if your way is "correct" (potentially circumstantially subjective, anyway), and you show us some possible _formats_ of the value used in substitution, but don't specify a problem with either. What's the question? You also lack other details, such as the initial format, character encoding, and whatnot.

Comment: @DFord then the symbol is not there. Which could be because your are using an incorrect encoding when reading the file

Comment: @RuneFS Which encoding would you recommend to read in the file? Right now I use `StreamReader` to read in the file and use `File.OpenText` to open the file. I use default encoding.

Comment: So this is really a question about why your attempt to find "®" has not been successful. In which case, you should really show us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Then we can advise you on what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: If I do not specify the encoding when reading the file, could that cause issues when comparing a character to ® such as `if(char == '®')`

Comment: question one: You need to use the right encoding (that is the one used when writing the file)
Question two yes it could create issue. in UTF-8 the hex is 0xC2AE but in ASCII it's 0xAE so reading an ASCII file as UTF-8 you would get the 0xC2AE. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure you're reading the text with the [correct encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx). It appears to me that you are using UTF-8, since you say `®` (Unicode code point U+00AE) is `0xC2AE`, which is [the same as UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/). You can use that like:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 0xc2, 0xae }) // "®", the registered symbol
// or
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
```

Once you've got it as a `string` in C#, you should use [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) to encode it as HTML.  E.g.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("SomeStuff®") // result is "SomeStuff&#174;"
```

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 I'm not entirely sure, I guessed the OP had a good enough reason. In the resulting HTML, you'd most likely want to encode things like `<` and `>`, which `HtmlEncode` does, so that you're not opening up injection vulnerabilities (unless this is a trusted .txt file that's intended to have that sort of thing).

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding you are decoding bytes with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string txt = "textwithsymbol";
        string html = "<html></html>";
        txt = txt.Replace("\u00ae", html);
```

Obviously you would replace the txt variable with the text you have read in and "\u00ae" is the symbol you are looking for.